How to Properly Use Axios with Next.js API Routes for Authentication and Handling Cookies?
I'm currently working on a Next.js project where I need to handle authentication and API requests using Axios. I'm a bit confused about whether I'm doing it right, especially when it comes to setting up Axios and handling cookies. Here's the setup I have so far:
Axios Setup
I created a singleton class for Axios to manage API requests:
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

export default class ExampleApi {
  private apiInstance: AxiosInstance;
  private static instance: ExampleApi;
  public _accessToken: string | undefined;

  private constructor(atoken?: string) {
    this.apiInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:4040/api",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      timeout: 3000,
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }

  public static getInstance(accessToken?: string): ExampleApi {
    if (!ExampleApi.instance) {
      ExampleApi.instance = new ExampleApi(accessToken);
    }

    return ExampleApi.instance;
  }

  public async post(api: string, body: any) {
    try {
      const res = await this.apiInstance.post(api, body);
      return {
        data: res.data,
        headers: res.headers,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }

  public async get(api: string, body: any) {
    const res = await this.apiInstance.get(api, body);
    return {
      data: res.data,
      headers: res.headers,
    };
  }
}

Next.js API Routes
Then, I use this ExampleApi class in my Next.js API routes like this:
GET EXAMPLE
import ExampleApi from "@service/app/services/exampleApi";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const cookies = req.headers.get('cookie');

  const res: any = await ExampleApi.getInstance().get("/account/info", {
    headers: { "Cookie": cookies }
  });

  const response = NextResponse.json(res.data.data);
  return response;
}

POST EXAMPLE
import ExampleApi from "@service/app/services/exampleApi";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const reqres = await request.json();
  const res: any = await ExampleApi.getInstance().post(
    "/account/login",
    {
      email: reqres.email,
      password: reqres.password,
    }
  );
  const response = NextResponse.json(res);
  const setCookieHeader = res.headers["set-cookie"];
  if (setCookieHeader) {
    setCookieHeader.forEach((cookie: string) => {
      response.headers.append("Set-Cookie", cookie);
    });
  }
  return response;
}

Am I handling cookies correctly in the GET and POST routes, especially with setting Set-Cookie headers in the response?
Is my approach to managing access tokens correct? How can I improve this, especially when storing and passing tokens in the headers?
